# count of non duplicate words that is greater than one

Tags: awk

There is a uniq command that returns the count of words like...

```
# cat tt.txt
test
this
and
that
and
test

# sort tt.txt | uniq -c
      2 and
      2 test
      1 that
      1 this
```

But is there a way to return words where count is greater than 1?

Expected results:

```
      and
      test
```

I can do this using python (pandas), but I will like to know a linux command so that it can be used in a shell script.

---

Update:

awk solution works, but does not look right. For e.g.

```
# echo "to" >> tt.txt
# echo "to" >> tt.txt
# echo "to" >> tt.txt

# awk '++a[$1] > 1' tt.txt
and
test
to
to
```

I do not see any reason why "to" will be repeated in the output.

Comment: `sort tt.txt | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1'`? Replace `1` with `2` for counts greater than `2`.

Comment: This is correct. But I need to print only text without the count.

Comment: Then `awk '$1 > 1 {print $2}'`. Please edit your question to add this important information.

Comment: Can you add this as answer?

Comment: Done. Note that this works only if your input lines contain only one word, as in your example. And note that `uniq -d`  is the best solution.

Comment: *I can do this using python (pandas), but I will like to know a linux command so that it can be used in a shell script.* - note that `python` is available in many linux machines, but `pandas` is not unless installed, therefore you might consider to use just `python` and its' standard library for that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a final filtering by `awk`:

```
$ sort tt.txt | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 {print $2}'
and
test
```

Comment: This is on the first page of the book "The awk Programming Language" written by authors of the tool. I really need to read it!

Comment: @shantanuo  "The awk Programming Language" isn't as useful or current as "Effective AWK Programming" by Arnold Robbins. If you want to learn awk get THAT book.

Answer (score 4):

That's what `uniq -d` is for:

```
$ sort tt.txt | uniq -d
and
test
$
```

And if you want to be able to specify the threshold, you can use awk like this:

```
$ awk '++c[$0] == 2' tt.txt 
and
test
$
```

Answer (score 3):

### Original answer

```
cat test.txt
test
this
and
that
and
test

awk '++a[$1] > 1' test.txt
and
test
```

### Edit

This solution doesn't work as I expected; if a word is in the file 3 times, it will print the word twice in the output.

You could correct this by using:

```
cat test.txt
test
this
and
that
and
test
to
to
to

awk '++a[$1] == 2' test.txt
and
test
to
```

Or, by filtering the resulting list to remove duplicates:

```
awk '++a[$1] > 1' test.txt | sort -u
and
test
to
```

Or load the words into an array and conduct the evaluation in an END statement:

```
awk '{++a[$1]} END{for (i in a) {if(a[i] > 1) {print i}}}' test.txt
and
test
to
```

But I see @oguz ismail has posted a better solution (+1), so I'd recommend using that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep:

```
sort tt.txt | uniq -c | grep --invert-match "  1 "
```

Note the space I had to put after the `1` since the number of occurrences can be more than 10

Comment: Upvoted. But not accpeted answer. if I change the criterion from 1 to 2 this will not work.

Comment: I agree, it specifically looks for words appearing exactly once.

Comment: This looks like a workaround :) | grep -v "  1 " | grep -v "  2 "

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'test
this
and
that
and
test' |
```

---

```
mawk '__[$_]++==!_'
```

---

```
and
test
```